# Ordenar Array em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um Array com números pares decrescentes:

`var a = [20, 18, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]`

quando chamo `a.sort()`, ele me retorna o seguinte:

`[0, 10, 18, 2, 20, 4, 6, 8]`

Esta ordenação não está correta. Como posso ordenar por ordem crescente corretamente?

Answer (score 6):

Você precisa passar a função de comparação:

```js
var a = [20, 18, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]
a.sort( (a,b) => a - b );
console.log(a);
```

O motivo disso é:

> Se funcaoDeComparacao não for informado, os elementos serão ordenados
>   de acordo com a sua conversão para texto e o texto comparado na
>   pontuação unicode do texto convertido. Por exemplo, "cherry" vem antes
>   de "banana". Em uma ordenação numérica, 9 vem antes de 80, mas porque
>   os números são convertidos para texto e, "80" vem antes de "9" na
>   ordenação Unicode.